# FlushFileBuffers Error - Handle is invalid - Error Number 6

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, file-io

Helllo,
I'm trying to do a `FlushFileBuffers()` and i always get an Error with number 6 - handle is invalid.

I also tried to do a `FlushFileBuffers()` for a whole drive volume and also for a specific file handle and i get the same result.

I try to flush the file buffers of a file handle of a remote process.

I try to do the following in a remote process.

```
public static bool FlushFileBuffersRemote(LockedFileEntry le)
{
    // StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(le.LockedFile);
    //UnloadModuleThreadProc umproc = new UnloadModuleThreadProc(UnloadModule);
    //IntPtr fpProc = Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(umproc);                                                                                                    
    IntPtr currentProcess = NativeMethods.GetCurrentProcess();
    int processId = le.ProcessID;

    //StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(le.LockedFile));

    try
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);

        IntPtr kernelMod = LoadLibrary("kernel32.dll");
        if (kernelMod == IntPtr.Zero)
            //throw new Exception("LoadLibrary of kernel32.dll failed");
            throw new Exception("Could not Flush File !");

        try
        {
            IntPtr freeLibraryAddr = GetProcAddress(kernelMod, "FlushFileBuffers");
            if (freeLibraryAddr == IntPtr.Zero)
                //throw new Exception("GetProcAddress of FreeLibrary failed");
                throw new Exception("Could not Flush File !");

            // Open the target process
            IntPtr proc = OpenProcess(ProcessAccessRights.PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, true, (uint)processId);

            //IntPtr proc = OpenProcess(ProcessAccessRights.PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | ProcessAccessRights.PROCESS_VM_OPERATION | ProcessAccessRights.PROCESS_VM_READ | ProcessAccessRights.PROCESS_VM_WRITE | ProcessAccessRights.PROCESS_CREATE_THREAD
            //, true, (uint)processId);

            if (proc == IntPtr.Zero)
                //throw new Exception("OpenProcess failed");
                throw new Exception("Could not Flush File !");

            SafeObjectHandle objectHandle = null;

            IntPtr handle = IntPtr.Zero;

            try
            {
                if (NativeMethods.DuplicateHandle(proc, le.HandlePtr, currentProcess, out objectHandle, 0, false, DuplicateHandleOptions.DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS))
                {
                    handle = objectHandle.DangerousGetHandle();
                }

                // Launch the thread, being FreeLibrary
                IntPtr remoteThreadHandle = CreateRemoteThread(proc, IntPtr.Zero, 0, freeLibraryAddr, handle, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
                if (remoteThreadHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
                    //throw new Exception("CreateRemoteThread failed");
                    throw new Exception("Could not Flush File !");

                return true;
            }
            finally
            {
                CloseHandle(proc);

                if (objectHandle != null)
                {
                    objectHandle.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            FreeLibrary(kernelMod);
        }

        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Module.ShowError(ex);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code that opened the handle?  Have you read through the FlushFileBuffers page and checked to make sure you're not passing a console handle and that the handle has GENERIC_WRITE access?  Have you tried writing a tiny sample program to see if that has the same problem?

Comment: Good Lord this is ugly code.  Odds that this can work are slim, handles have process affinity.  At least DuplicateHandle is required.  If this is actually an attempt to get a file unlocked then don't bother, flushing buffers doesn't close a handle.

Comment: I tried to do a DuplicateHandle but with no result. Is it possible to flush a file that has been opened by a remote process ?

Comment: @alexandertr: Do you know what `DuplicateHandle` does? Why are you telling it to duplicate a handle that doesn't exist, from your own process to your own process?!

Comment: See the comment of Hans Passant he told something about DuplicateHandle. Also i have got a process handle with OpenProcess before i do that. Is there a way to FlushFileBuffers of a remote process?

Comment: Isn't this C# (Maybe C++/CLI)?